# cakephp pagination with condition

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, string-concatenation

I already defined condition variable values. I need to write this formate how can i write this.

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array('conditions' => array(
    if(!empty($this->request->data['filter']['delivery']))
    {
    'Gig.delivery <=' => $this->request->data['filter']['delivery'],
    }
    if(!empty($this->request->data['filter']['delivering']))
    {
    "Gig.bangsalsodelivering IN ({$csv_deliveringfilters})",
    }
    if(!empty($this->request->data['filter']['servicetype']))
    {
    "Gig.bangsservicetype IN ({$csv_bangsservicetypesfilters})",
    }
    if(!empty($this->request->data['filter']['style']))
    {
    "Gig.bangsstyles IN ({$csv_stylefilters})",
    }
    if(!empty($this->request->data['filter']['fileformate']))
    {
    "Gig.bangsfileformates IN ({$csv_fileformatefilters})",
    }
));
$agetGigsItem = $this->Paginator->paginate('Gig');
```

Answer (score 2):

### Conditions are normally an array

Conditions are normally handled as an array, *not* as a string. so for example this:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = [
    'conditions' => ['Gig.field' => 'is this value']
];

$agetGigsItem = $this->Paginator->paginate('Gig');
```

Would apply this sql condition:

```
WHERE Gig.field = "is this value"
```

It is *a bad idea* to build conditions using string concatenation. In addition to being more cumbersome it means you'll need to handle escaping of user input yourself.

### Working solution

Given the code in the question this would do what is asked:

```
$conditions = [];
$filter = $this->request->data['filter'];

if(!empty($filter['delivery'])) {
    $conditions['Gig.delivery <='] = $filter['delivery'];
}

if(!empty($filter['delivering'])) {
    $conditions['Gig.bangsalsodelivering'] = explode(',', $filter['delivering']);
}

if(!empty($filter['servicetype'])) {
    $conditions['Gig.bangsservicetype'] = explode(',', $filter['servicetype']);
}

if(!empty($filter['style'])) {
    $conditions['Gig.bangsstyles'] = explode(',', $filter['style']);
}

if(!empty($filter['fileformate'])) {
    $conditions['Gig.bangsfileformates'] = explode(',', $filter['fileformate']);
}

$this->Paginator->settings['conditions'] = $conditions;
$agetGigsItem = $this->Paginator->paginate('Gig');
```

Note that array values are automatically converted to `IN ()` condition clauses, and the comparison if it's not equals - is in the array key.

Be sure to check [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/contents.html) for the version you are using, to know more about [how to use pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html) and [how to query the database](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table).

Comment: i am using check boxes so i need IN in my question $csv_bangsservicetypesfilters varible have imploded checkboxes value

Comment: `$csv_bangsservicetypesfilters` is not defined in the question - I'll leave it to you to figure out how to make use of this mystery variable.

Comment: but in this i am getting this answer WHERE `Gig`.`bangsfileformates` IS NULL LIMIT 20

Comment: You must put some effort into figuring that out - I can't tell you what to do because there's no info in the question to tell me why that's the case. Your question is also still full of parse errors. If you expect people to spend time answering your question _spend time writing a good question_. Good luck.